# Explain why storing the value of printf in a variable and then printing it gives an extra value?

Tags: printf

`int d;
    d=printf("\n%d%d%d%d",1,2,3,4);
    printf("%d",d);`

The code gives the output as 1,2,3,4,5.
I don't understand why an integer greater than the last one is being printed.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf

Answer (score 1):

`printf` returns the total number of characters written. In the first `printf` call that is 4 digits from the 4 variables and the newline character which adds up to 5. So the return value is 5 which is what you get in the second call.